# Using libuv to watch for file changes

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, google-nativeclient, libuv

I want to build a Chrome Extension for the Developer Tools that watches for changes a given folder and refreshes/updates the CSS/JS/image files in the browser.

There is a similar approach already:

http://tin.cr

Tin.cr uses NPAPI which is not sandboxed and has some security issues, so I can't use it in some dev environments where company polices have strict rules (specially in the financial industry).

Another approach is to use NaCl (Chrome's Native Client, which is sandboxed).

I am a front-end dev, with little knowledge in C, so I need some help, please.

How can I watch/monitor file changes in libuv? If someone could provide a code snippet I would greatly appreciate it.

From what I understand from the docs, libuv would allow the extension to work cross-platform, am I wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

NaCl doesn't have an API to watch changes in a given folder on disk. Can you use Google Drive? Google Drive has an API for getting list of changed files: https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/changes/list.

Comment: I know NaCl doesn't have an API to watch for changes, that's why I want to use libuv, which from the docs I understand it provides a cross-platform API

Comment: Any library must use NaCl API in the end. If NaCl doesn't have necessary functions, library can not work.